# Create model for unlabeled data

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic, predictive-models

model_pred_gender   0   1    # Confusion matrix structure is not corresct. it is issue.
                1 314 698

model_pred_gender[pred>0.6] <- "1"   # Now I changed pred > 0.6

tab<-table(model_pred_gender,vdata$Gender)    # Confusion matrix creation
print(tab)

model_pred_gender   0   1
                0  32  33
                1 282 665

Comment: Did you try logistic regression? That should be (much) more appropriate than cluster analysis!

Comment: I tried . Please visit my steps. http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11887/kjetil-b-halvorsen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it. Make 2 parts of your dataset: a) where gender information is present b) where gender information is missing.

Now dataset from a is the one, on which you will build your model and dataset from part b is the one you are going to predict.

For the dataset from a, treat your gender as (1/0) 2 classes and apply binary logistic model with InterestID as independent variable.Note that you need to transform your InterestID into indicators for each of the category and then remove duplicates for customer ID. If it turns out to be good predictor. Use the estimates of the model to predict the probability of the gender being male or female in dataset from b.

So your train dataset will be like:

```
  UserID  Gender(this is target) InterestID_1 InterestID_2 InterestID_3...
    3            1                      1            0            0
    4            1                      1            1            0 
........
```

Comment: I created 2 type data set .First dataset have userID with respective Gender infrmation and user selected InterestID .Another dataset have userID with respective missing Gender infrmation(NA) and user selected InterestID. For first dataset, I removed userID and based on user's gender (0/1) and their selected interested ID . created 2 cluster.

Comment: I don't think this will work. Going on the data summary it appears that InterestID is measured repeatably for users. Making a binary logistic model that predicts Gender from InterestID will make it possible for a single person to be assigned multiple genders. A logistic mixed model may do the trick, but is predicting Gender from InterestID your ultimate goal? Or is it a step in between to deal with missing data? If your ultimate goal is to predict InterestID from Gender than doing the reverse first to deal with missing data will bias your results.

Comment: My ultimate goal is predicting Gender from InterestID.

Comment: @Niek You are right. So I suggested him to make indicators for various categories of InterestID and remove the duplicates at User Level. that should do the trick.

Comment: I have 2 type  data set .First dataset have userID with respective Gender infrmation and user selected InterestID .Another dataset have userID with respective missing Gender infrmation(NA) and user selected InterestID. For first dataset, in data cleaning process,I removed userID. Now I have user's gender (0/1) and their selected interested ID. My ultimate goal is predict Gender based on selected InterestID for second dataset (unlabeled Gender).

Comment: I don't believe it will solve the issue. The model assumes that observations are independent but non-duplicate in this case does not make the observations independent. If you want to use a simple model and this is the only predictor that you have for Gender (I notice you left one variable out of your summary) I would take some aggregate of InterestID like the mean or median per person and use that to predict Gender. This  makes observations independent and on the same (person) level instead of the dependent variable on a person level and the independent variable on a measurement level.

Comment: @Niek Observations will be independent, since we are not keeping the InterestID as one of the variables, but multiple indicators corresponding to a user. Think of InterestID as a factor with multilevels and not as continuous number

Comment: During profile creation , user shown interest for different sectionl like Fashion, sports, Food....etc and it's mapped in database as InterestID (Fashion :1 , Sports :2, Food: 3,................Movie:11).So based on selected Interest by (Male :1/Female :2) Gender. I need to identify pattern/ cluster and build such a model So I can predict Gender for unlabeled data(Gender.)

Comment: Interest ID range : 1,2,3.............11. User can show interest in multiples. like Quora we are selecting area of interest.

Comment: @KumarP I updated in the answer. Create your dataset like that and then remove InterestID and keep the dataset unique at userlevel. Do the same for test dataset, while predicting.

Comment: Agree with @muni altering your dataset in this way gives a better representation of your problem and can be used with a logistic regression model to make predictions about a persons Gender if the model makes adequate predictions. I misunderstood your data, so you can ignore previous comments. When using the dataset for other analyses after imputing Gender values in this manner, the relation between Gender and the InterestID variables will be overstated which is something to keep in mind. The article by Schafer & Graham (2002)  may help if you want to treat this as a missing data problem.

Comment: UserID              Gender        InterestID    
 Min.   :   3.0     Min.   :1.000   Min.   : 1.000  
 1st Qu.: 503.0     1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.: 2.000  
 3rd Qu.:1479.2     3rd Qu.:2.000   3rd Qu.: 8.000  
 Max.   :1766.0     Max.   :2.000   Max.   :11.000  
> xtabs(~Gender + InterestID,data=NEWDATA)
      InterestID
Gender   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
     1 209 157  97 126 155 161 119 130 119 160 113
     2 461 481 206 287 343 299 358 404 170 201 244

Comment: you still don't get it. transform the data as per the dataframe in my answer, then fit the model : glm(Gender~InterestID_1+InterestID_2..

Comment: I tried logistic regression. please visit my steps. @muni             http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/124691/muni

Comment: share your dataset

Comment: UserID
Gender
InterestID
1
3
1
1
2
3
1
6
3
4
2
2
4
4
2
1
5
4
2
7
6
4
2
8
7
4
2
5
8
4
2
6
9
5
2
2                    http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/124691/muni

Comment: I used dcast function for frequency count .                                                                                       dcast(UserID +Gender ~InterestID,data=Mydata). Now data look like this.          > dcast(UserID +Gender ~InterestID,data=Mydata)
Using InterestID as value column: use value.var to override.
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
    UserID Gender 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
1        3      0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0
2        4      1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0  0  0

Comment: Thanks a lot  @muni. stats.stackexchange.com/users/124691/muni